# PHP (or Javascript) Floating Header On/Off

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I recently implemented a floating(?) header on my website using CSS, but I would like to make it so that particular pages just have a normal header, as the nature of some pages do not warrant it. In the future (or maybe at the same time?) I'd like to give users the option to toggle the floating, if that makes sense.

(Bear with me here, I'm still a PHP/Javascript novice!)

So, currently the header will stay visible at the top of the window, even when the user scrolls down the page, on all pages.
However, there are pages where a floating header would be unnecessary. With other pages where it would be necessary, I'd like users to have the option to toggle the floating header, as some people may not need quick access to the tool links in the header. Ideally, there would be a css button constantly visible in the top-right corner, that says something like 'View/Hide Navbar' or 'Stop following me!' (I'm more concerned with the actual functionality at the moment.) SO regardless of whether the header is visible or hidden, that Toggle button would always need to be visible.

Whether I would give users the option to Toggle the header on all pages (even on pages without the floating header), I don't know. Depends on how difficult it is to implement.

So far, I've done this to show the header on all pages:

```
    #header
{
    position:fixed;
    width:914px;
    z-index:1;
}

    #rest of header content....
```

and on each .php page, I've put the header background and navigation bar in a .
That's all fine and dandy so far.

Using PHP or Javascript, how can I introduce a toggle function?

Comment: There is no obvious PHP link here - what you describe involves HTML, CSS and, if you want to remember the user's selection choice, JavaScript (though granted the latter part *could* be done with PHP)

Comment: this is something you can achieve with javascript and cookies, php seems uncessary

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that... If there are any solutions using Javascript, I'd be interested to hear it! :)

Comment: I've also edited the question to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty simple - in a checkbox or any form of user setting implementation you like to choose - make it activate a PHP function you're gonna make. That function (doesn't have to actually be a function, mind you) will save the user's preference of the header. You can do this via:

1. **Sessions** - will reset when the browser closes
2. **Cookies** - will reset either when browser closes or on a specific time
   depending on your doing
3. **Database** - will reset only when you tell it to - along with other user preferences (are you familiar with dynamic
   content yet?)

Assuming you don't want a data overload and you're not forcing people to join your website (and don't want to open arbitrary temporary accounts for every visitor) - I'd say go with **cookies** and set them to expire in a date far from now. PHP has a [built in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for cookies:

```
setcookie ($name , $value, $expire);
```

For example:

```
setcookie('header_float', 'true', time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

Will set a cookie to expire one year from now. You can access this cookie with the `$_COOKIE['header_float']` superglobal variable.

```
<div id="header" <?=($_COOKIE['header_float']) ? ' class="float"' : ''?>>
...
</div>
```

Comment: But will that allow a toggle function? From what I can understand, that will just set it to 'off' for a year, without being able to turn it on again... But then again, I have limited knowledge!

Comment: Make the toggle function yourself - use any form you like, like a link, a checkbox, whatever - that will trigger the code. setcookie should use `true` or `false` respectively with the way you made that work, and checking whether it's true or false will let you decide if you want the header to float or not.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to this would be to set a class on `<body>` or even `<html>`:

```
<body class="fixed-header">
```

vs.

```
<body class="">
```

and have your CSS react to that class.

```
.fixed-header #header {
    position:fixed;
    width:914px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

(It doesn't matter if you set that class through PHP or Javascript.)

Comment: Ok, that does make sense for the non-floating header pages. Not sure why I didn't think of that :P

Comment: Like @SmokeyPHP suggested, you could also set that class on the header element itself - but you'd be giving up some flexibility. Setting this sort of stuff on a root element (`html` or `body`) allows every element to react. Say you wanted your `#content` to have a certain `margin-top` if the header was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The code will of course be different for you, but below is a way in which it can be achieved. Basically PHP adds a class to the `div` if it's a page that doesn't want to have the 'floating' header.

```
<div id="header"<?php echo in_array($page,array('ignore-page','ignore-page2')) ? ' class="static"' : ''; ?>>
    blah
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header
{
    position:fixed;
    width:914px;
    z-index:1;
}

#header.static {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: with the 'ignore-page and 'ignore-page2' - would they be the names of the PHP files? For example, contact.php, or home.php? Or does it not require the extension? I've added the .htaccess rule that removes file extensions from the address bar and URLs, so will I need to take that into account?

Comment: It depends how (and if) you store page names in a variable. If you pull in the page name from a get request using the htaccess, you could put in a global included file `$page = $_GET['page'];` (or something to that effect), then use the file names in the array however they're stored in that variable (from what you've said, without the extension)

Comment: Well, I've created a config.php file, which has a few variables in. For example, there will be some pages that will be in different directories across the website, yet still rely on one style.css. So in config.php, I've added `$CONF['stylesheet']='http://example.com/style.css';`, so whenever I link to the .css from any page, I don't need to worry about working out what the directory location is. I know you can use `('../style.css') in some instances, but I did it as way to test my new-found knowledge of variables (still a work in progress though...)